# Using Mac OS X terminal to copy a selection of folders to a new location, with merge behavior

Tags: macos, bash, grep, terminal.app

I have a folder 'foo' that contains a lot of sub folders, e.g.

```
foo
 |---20101
 |---20102
 |---20103
 |---20111
 |---20112
 |---20113
```

There are way more than this, but hopefully it explains the scenario. I now want to copy all folders from this folder that start '2011' into a sibling of 'foo' called 'bar'. However, 'bar' already contains some folders with the same name

```
bar
 |---20111
 |---20113
 |---20114
```

The contents of the source and destination folder should be merged. Notice that the script will also need to create a bar/20112 folder as that doesn't exist.

I'm new to Mac Terminal scripting and have successfully managed to grep the right folders

```
foo>ls | grep ^2011
```

Which lists the right folders, but I've no idea how to pipe that over to an appropriate copy operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The copy command is `cp`. If you give it the `-r` (recursive) flag, it will do exactly what you want, it will copy files into existing folders and create new folders when the destination folder is missing.

However, [you should never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you should use `find` or, even simpler, [bash globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html):

```
cp -rv foo/2011* bar/
```

If there are files as well as folders whose name begins with `2011`, use `find` and its `-exec` option which will apply whatever command you give it to everything found by `find` (referred to as `{}`):

```
find foo/ -type d -name "2011*" -exec cp -rv '{}' bar/ \;
```

In this specific case there is no reason to save the output of a command and pass it to `cp`. This is sometimes necessary though so here's how its done. In general, the output of a command can be given as input to another command if placed inside inverted comas or `$()`.

```
cp -rv `find foo/ -type d -name "2011*"` bar/
```

or

```
cp -rv $(find foo/ -type d -name "2011*") bar/
```

Alternatively, you can loop through the results:

```
for dir in $(find foo/ -type d -name "2011*"); do cp -rv "$dir" bar/; done
```

This gets more complicated if your file/folder names can contain special characters or new lines and the like, in that case you should do something like this:

```
find foo/ -type d -name "2011*" | while IFS= read -r dir; do 
       cp -rv "$dir" bar/; 
done
```